# What does "hundred to no" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: ambiguity

> Then why didn’t humans abandon farming when the plan backfired? Partly because it took generations for the small changes to accumulate and transform society and, by then, nobody remembered that they had ever lived differently. And partly because population growth burned humanity’s boats. If the adoption of ploughing increased a village’s population ***from a hundred to no***, which ten people would have volunteered to starve so that the others could go back to the good old times? There was no going back. The trap snapped shut.

The paragraph is from the book _[Sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapiens:_A_Brief_History_of_Humankind). It didn't make sense to me. I googled to check if I can find similar usage but couldn't find anything.
It says adoption of ploughing increased the population but later says a hundred to no which I think it means hundred to non. This means decreasing

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because based on the best answer, it appears that the question is predicated on a false premise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question arises from an OCR-induced typographical error.

Answer (score 7):

A quick online search for any of the phrases in this paragraph indicates that the number "110" has been misinterpreted by optical character recognition as "no".

Proof?

- [The book is quoted elsewhere](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/18962767-itsur-toldot-ha-enoshut?page=63) with the phrase reading "If the adoption of ploughing increased a village’s population from a hundred to **110**, which ten people..."
- On [this page](https://erenow.net/common/sapiensbriefhistory/21.php), where the error appears, a user comments, "seems that 110 was numerised [sic] as 'no'".
- The context itself indicates an increase from 100 to 110, as the rest of the sentence addresses feeding the additional 10 people.

Comment: Please don't rush to answer questions which are clearly off-topic. Gross misprints are one area.